# Memory error when sorting a numpy memmap array

Tags: numpy, numpy-memmap, memmap

I have a numpy-memmap matrix `S` of size 12 GB. And I'm trying to argsort each row. To do that I have defined another memmap array `first_k` to save the result. The problem is that a memory error occurs.

Here is the code:

```
first_k = np.memmap('first_k', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=S.shape)
first_k[:] = np.memmap.argsort(S, axis=1)
```

Any possible solutions? 
I am thinking to process it in slices ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: argsort allocates an output buffer for indices in *RAM*. It may be even 24GiB because ```signed long``` type is likely used. You run out of RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I process the memmap in slices. Here is the code.

```
N = S.shape[0]
first_k = np.memmap('first_k', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(N, N))        
del first_k

step = 1000
for row in np.arange(0, N, step):
    size = min(step, N-row)
    first_k = np.memmap('first_k',
                        dtype='float32',
                        mode='r+',
                        shape=(size, N),
                        offset=4*N*row)

    first_k[:] = np.memmap.argsort(S[row:row+size], axis=1)
    del first_k
```